Using a passport as id for a check in lieu of a driver's license
In light of this question and its answers and comments, I have a question.
I am  a US expat living abroad for many years.  On one visit to the US (NY state), I tried to pay in a store with a check (personal check, on a US bank where I still had an account).  The cashier wanted, of course, a driver's license.  I no longer had one.  I tried to use my passport but she did not consider it valid id and would not allow me to pay by check (I don't remember how I paid :-) ).
The question I referred to relates to the issue of what to use for id when visiting the US:


She wants to keep it for Identification she needs for paperwork, etc when conferring with her US bank accounts, etc.

As someone who resides outside the US, she should use her passport as
identification when visiting the US.

Apparently though, it does not always work.  How can an expat use a personal check, when visiting the US? If it is the passport, is there somewhere this is documented?  Something I could print out and show to a cashier who does not know?

"but she did not consider it valid id" that is beyond stupid. There is no requirement to even have a drivers license. What if you are legally blind? Do they want to see your drivers license? I don't think that person would have been convinced, no matter what you explained to them. If someone doesn't have common sense to be convinced by the obvious, showing them a page copied from the law will do very little.

Could be.   I don't remember whether she asked her manager.  But if we expats are supposed to use our passport for id, but it is not always accepted, then we have a problem, no?  Even if the people are idiots, we're the ones who then can't pay!   As for blind or whatever, the DMV in NY also offers a non-driver id, for many years already, IIRC.

@nvoigt There is also no requirement to have any ID, what does that have to do with anything? In many US states, it's actually possible to get a non-driver identification card from the agency issuing driving licenses. Can you stop making ignorant comments about ID law or US practices? Your “common sense” seems to be mostly an assumption that every place should be like Germany…

My "common sense" is that since I could use my foreign passport in all kinds of places to get IDd in the US, they should accept a US passport as well. No idea what that has to do with Germany.

@nvoigt You wrote “There is no requirement to even have a drivers license.“ But there is no requirement to even have a passport or any specific document in the US. This sentence only makes sense in the German context where there is in fact such a requirement. Same thing for your comment elsewhere about driving license not being an official ID document in Europe, which multiple commenters had to explain is simply not true.

@Relaxed I never said there is a requirement to have a passport. Or other ID. And yes, my comment elsewhere was wrong, I have deleted it, so please stop arguing it by proxy here. I see nothing wrong about my comment other than you interpreting things into it it doesn't actually say.

@nvoigt How are we supposed to understand the sentence I quoted then? How is the fact that “there is no requirement to even have a drivers license” at all relevant to the question, let alone a reason to think expecting one is “beyond stupid” now that you understand there is no document you're required to have?

I have no idea what your problem is with parsing that sentence. When someone asks for your drivers license and won't accept other types of ID, the sentence "you are not even required to have a drivers license" makes perfect sense to me. Given the fact that, in fact, you don't have to have one. Whether any other ID is mandatory changes absolutely nothing about that sentence.

@nvoigt Well since there is no document that anybody has to have, how is that supposed to guide what document to accept? Since it makes perfect sense to you, you can surely explain it without playing dumb…

You can't control every decision of every cashier. There's no requirement for US citizens to have any type of ID, and many in New York do not have driving licenses.
Passport is in fact the only ID to which every US citizen is entitled.
You mentioned "printed out" - any photocopy is not a valid ID. You need the actual passport.
And paying by check - get a debit card. Checks are the worst payment method ever.

"Passport is in fact the only ID to which every US citizen is entitled to." They can be denied US passports for having a certain amount of unpaid child support or unpaid taxes, or for foreign policy / national security reasons (e.g. Philip Agee).

I wasn't talking about printing out a copy of the password.  I meant printing out something to give the cashier explaining that a passport is supposed to be usable as an id.

"many in New York do not have driving licenses" - that is why they have the non driver id.

"And paying by check - get a debit card." - Yeah, eventually I did that.  But, checks are supposed to be usable  :-)

I don't think you can get a state id without being a resident there

@Basya: The store can accept or reject any mode of payment they like. Lots of stores do not accept checks, or only accept them if you meet some arbitrary requirements. For example, if you're a resident of a foreign country, the store might not want to put up with the complexity of chasing you down if the check bounces, because it's much harder than chasing down a local. There is nothing to "explain" to the cashier, or their boss, because they were entirely within their rights to refuse your check.

@Kevin - she refused my check not because I lived abroad.  She told me straight that the passport was not a form of identification they would accept.  This sounded rather outrageous to me.

@Basya: In the US, there is no practical difference between "we don't accept passports" and "we don't accept checks from non-residents," because the vast majority of residents have either a driver's license or a non-driver's ID (but relatively fewer Americans have passports). Actually, that's not true. There is one difference: It is very easy for the clerk to look at a passport and say "we don't accept this," but it is much harder for the clerk to verify your country of residence. So they just don't take passports as a loose proxy for not taking non-resident checks.

@Basya not a form of identification they would accept. It's entirely within their right to decide what to accept, if they don't want to accept passports they won't.

The only somewhat relevant requirement I can find about what forms of payments stores have to accept is a requirement that New York City stores accept cash. Since the aren't even required to accept checks, I'd be surprised to find a requirement that if they choose to accept them at all, they then must accept specified forms of ID.

That makes some sense.  But....checks notwithstanding, are there any known guidelines about what is considered valid identification?

@baysa For US domestic flights, US and foreign passports can be used to board. If you need a notarization, US passports are OK as ID; foreign passports may or may not be depending on the state.
